# Add a data directory outside Python package directory

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-importlib

Given the following directory structure for a package `my_package`:

```
/
├── data/
│   ├── more_data/
│   └── foo.txt
├── my_package/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── stuff/
│       └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
```

How can I make the `data/` directory accessible (in the most Pythonic way) from within code, without using `__file__` or other hacky solutions? I have tried using `data_files` in `setup.py` and the `[options.package_data]` in `setup.cfg` to no avail.

I would like to do something like:

```py
dir_data = importlib.resources.files(data)
csv_files = dir_data.glob('*.csv')
```

**EDIT:**

I'm working with an editable installation and there's already a `data/` directory in the package (for source code unrelated to the top-level data).

Comment: What do you mean by saying make accessible? Do you mean it is not a Python package and you cannot import from it?

Comment: Is there a good reason you don't have the data subdirectory _inside_ the package? That would be more usual. Please add the `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` contents into question.

Comment: define a path as env variable and use that path in your package, is this pythonic? :) now always your package could look for the specific env variable to see where are the data

Comment: The easy thing to do would be to move `data/` to `my_package/data/`. If not possible, you can do some tricks in `setup.py` to "fix" it at build-time with `package_dir`. I have an answer for this somewhere, but I would need to search it.

Comment: Yes, the easy thing would be to move `data/` into the package, but the package already has a `data`/ directory with code, so it would be quite messy to have both source code and data files in the same directory.

Comment: It doesn't have to be actually named `data`.  Call it `my_package/other_data` or anything else if you want ..

Comment: Show your `setup.py`  and/or `setup.cfg` and/or `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: Most pythonic? Then probably move the directory inside the package. https://youtu.be/ZsGFU2qh73E. You'll have to rename one of your`data` directories Or swap around which one is in the package

Comment: Do you really want to package and distribute the contents of the `data/` directory or do you really just want to open a bunch of settings and files, which could be located anywhere on your system?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 solutions. For both solutions, the object is to move data into the top-level importable package (that is why it is called "*package data*"). This means the data will be accessible via something like the following:

```
importlib.resource.files('mypackage.data')
```

---

***1.*** Move files in the source code repository

One easy and straightforward solution is to move the `data/` directory to `my_package/data/`. And then do the packaging as usual.

---

***2.*** Let *setuptools* "move" the data at build-time

With the [*`package_dir`*](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-package-dir) feature of *setuptools*, it is possible to modify the directory structure at build time.

Be aware that this approach does not work with "*editable installations*".

It could look like this in `setup.cfg` (untested):

```
[options]
# ...
package_dir=
    my_package=my_package
    my_package.data=data
```

Comment: Moving the data is not an option, as I'm working with an editable installation and there's already a `data/` directory in the package (for source code unrelated to the top-level data).

Comment: It would have been better if you had written these details in your question right from the start. You are more likely to get helpful answers if you provide all the relevant details.

Comment: Yes indeed, that was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty `data/__init__.py` file, so that `data` becomes a top-level import package, so that the data files become *package data*, so that they are accessible via `importlib.resources.files('data')`. This should work with "*editable installation*". You might need to do small changes in your packaging files (`setup.py` or `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`).